# flutter windows printing plugin gives CMake compile time error

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-desktop

I'm working on flutter desktop application and using printing flutter plugin to print document. The code was running perfectly fine. After i did flutter clean and try to again run that code it give this error. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byDMh.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byDMh.png). The line of code where it is giving error is also in this screenshot [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyciE.png)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyciE.png).

It is required to download some files for windows. As mentioned here in the link from above screenshot .
https://github.com/bblanchon/pdfium-binaries

When i try to manually download that files from the link where it is giving error in above screenshot, it says Not Found error on download

I did try latest version of this printing plugin but it that latest version is incompatible with my sdk version (1.26.0-1.0.pre • channel dev).

Can anyone help me please. Thanks in advance.